# Retrieving user's uploaded videos on youtube without any authentication

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am making a rails(3.0.11) application using youtube_it api. Is it possible to get the uploaded videos of a user by using only his youtube account id/google account id, and without any kind of authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User uploads feed does not need authentication. You can access the feed at:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<user-id>/uploads

Comment: I know its too late, but thanx :)